# How to listen to webhooks in UWP

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, windows-10-universal

I'm working on a UWP desktop app that has a trello integration using my own Api wrapper. I got to the part where I need to have realtime updates when a model changes inside trello ( a board, card etc...)
For testing purposes I used [webhook.site](https://webhook.site/) to generate a callback Url.

The issue I'm facing is that I can't find a way to listen to that URL from inside my UWP app. I thought HttpListener would work but it doesn't seem to.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you explain listen to that URL from inside UWP app, Do you render trello  with WebView control?

Comment: No. No webview is being used I'm using the trello API so everything is built from scratch.
Basically, everytime I modify a card or a board etc, trello will send a post request to the webhook URL. My UWP app should listen to that URL so whenever it receives the POST request, I can refresh the UI.
It's like chat apps where you don't have to manually refresh the chat to see new messages